# Unable to activate constraint with anchors while adding a textfield

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, nslayoutconstraint, appdelegate

A while ago I started creating my screens via the storyboard.

Recently I have been convinced doing it programmatically.

Currently I am running into the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors  and  because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

   var emailTextField: UITextField {

        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.placeholder = "email";
        tf.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.03)
        tf.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        tf.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)

        return tf
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white

        view.addSubview(emailTextField)

        emailTextField.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 40, paddingLeft: 20, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 20, width: 0, height: 40)
    }

}
```

I have created a function to anchor my elements in Extensions.swift:

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {

    func anchor(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, left: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, right: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, paddingTop: CGFloat, paddingLeft: CGFloat, paddingBottom: CGFloat, paddingRight: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {

        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        if let top = top {
            self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: paddingTop).isActive = true
        }

        if let left = left {
            self.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: left, constant: paddingLeft).isActive = true
        }

        if let bottom = bottom {
            self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -paddingBottom).isActive = true
        }

        if let right = right {
            self.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: right, constant: -paddingRight).isActive = true
        }

        if width != 0 {
            widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
        }

        if height != 0 {
            heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true
        }


    }
}
```

In addition, I deleted the Application Scene Manifest in `Info.plist`.

I want my project to support the upcoming iOS versions starting at 13.0.
Nevertheless I don't want to use the new framework SwiftUI.

Are there any specific things to watch out for (e.g. Scene Delegate)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change this

```
var emailTextField: UITextField {

    let tf = UITextField()
    tf.placeholder = "email";
    tf.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.03)
    tf.borderStyle = .roundedRect
    tf.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)

    return tf
}
```

into this

```
var emailTextField: UITextField = {

    let tf = UITextField()
    tf.placeholder = "email";
    tf.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.03)
    tf.borderStyle = .roundedRect
    tf.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)

    return tf
}()
```

In current version `emailTextField` is computed property, so, every time you access it compiler create a new instance (it works like function, not variable).

Comment: Thanks for that! However: Now only a black screen is displayed instead of the white background and the textfield

Comment: inspect its frame (its height can be 0) and don't forget to set background to UITextField itself.

Comment: Nice. Had the same problem and now I just realised what was happening! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Textfield was unable to get its parent view while you were adding its constraint. Below code works for me. I passed current view as a param to anchor() method and add emailTextField as a subview there.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var emailTextField:UITextField = {
     let tf = UITextField()
     tf.placeholder = "email";
     tf.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.03)
     tf.borderStyle = .roundedRect
     tf.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
     return tf
  }()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      view.backgroundColor = .white
      emailTextField.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 40, paddingLeft: 20, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 20, width: 0, height: 40, view:view)
   }


 }


extension UIView {

     func anchor(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, left: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, right: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, paddingTop: CGFloat, paddingLeft: CGFloat, paddingBottom: CGFloat, paddingRight: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat, view:UIView) {

        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(self)
        if let top = top {
           self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: paddingTop).isActive = true
        }

        if let left = left {
             self.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: left, constant: paddingLeft).isActive = true
        }

         if let bottom = bottom {
             self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -paddingBottom).isActive = true
         }

         if let right = right {
            self.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: right, constant: -paddingRight).isActive = true
        }

         if width != 0 {
            widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
         }

         if height != 0 {
             heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true
         }
      }
}
```